# MySql stored procedure returns value error

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I am using the following stored procedure:

```
DELIMITER $$ 
USE `customer`$$ 
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `InsertCustomerEmail`$$ 

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `InsertCustomerEmail`(IN p_Customer_ID INT(11), 
                                  IN p_from_who VARCHAR(50), 
                                  IN p_to_whom VARCHAR(50), 
                                  IN p_CC VARCHAR(50), 
                                  IN p_BCC VARCHAR(50), 
                                  IN p_Subject VARCHAR(500), 
                                  IN p_Massage VARCHAR(4000), 
                                  IN p_Is_Sent BIT(1), 
                                  IN p_Sent_When DATE, 
                                  IN p_Is_Active BIT(1), 
                                  OUT new_ID INT) 
BEGIN 
    INSERT INTO customer_emails ( 
        `Customer_ID`, 
        `from_who`, 
        `to_whom`, 
        `CC`, 
        `BCC`, 
        `Subject`, 
        `Massage`, 
        `Is_Sent`, 
        `Sent_When`, 
        `Is_Active` 
        ) VALUES (p_Customer_ID, 
              p_from_who, 
              p_to_whom, 
              p_CC, 
              p_BCC, 
              p_Subject, 
              p_Massage, 
              p_Is_Sent, 
              p_Sent_When, 
              p_Is_Active); 
    SET @new_ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 
END$$ 
DELIMITER ;
```

My database has an auto increment ID column, I would like to return this `ID` (the last one added) in the `New_ID` variable but when I run the CALL for the procedure it returns `NULL` for the `New_ID`.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Tag the dbms used, that code doesn't look like ANSI SQL at all.

Comment: Tagged in 2nd row, the procedure will insert the datas in the table I have problem getting back the last insert's ID

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read [ask].

Comment: What's `@new_ID`? Try `SET new_ID = SCOPE_IDENTITY();` instead.

Comment: Tryed, still get "NULL" for the the new_ID value :(

Comment: Maybe you should show us the calling code as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being the `@new_ID` assignment is not considered part of the transaction; the `INSERT` statement is. Move the following line outside the `BEGIN ... END`

```
SET @new_ID=SCOPE_IDENTITY();
```

Since you have only one operation in the batch, you can loose the `BEGIN...END`

**EDIT**

As Thorsten Dittmar suggested I need to explain a bit further.
The `@new_ID` assignment is executed right away, since it is not considered DML action and is not part of the batch. Thus `SCOPE_IDENTITTY()` is executed, but there is no identity generated yet, because the `INSERT` statement IS considered part of the batch and it is executed at its end.

**EDIT 2**

Since the OP added `MySQL` tag, above statement won't work, since there is no `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in MySQL. Instead the correct function is `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.

```
SET @new_ID=LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: How's that supposed to help?

Comment: `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` returns the last identity inserted. The actual insert is not performed until the batch is closed...

Comment: I'd consider this part of the answer, don't you think?

Comment: Unfortunately still the same result :S The dates get into the table bit the value is still NULL

Comment: @ThorstenDittmar: Point taken. I've edited my answer.

Comment: @Stonesmit: Isn't there some error or warning? I just realized we're talking about MySQL and it appears to NOT have `SCOPE_IDENTITY`. Instead it has `LAST_INSERT_ID()`. So give it a try ...

Comment: Tryed both ways, no erro just this massage "Query: select @new_ID 1 row(s) affected"

Comment: Definitely there is no `SCOPE_IDENTITY()` in MySQL. I've just created a fiddle. [Check it out](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/70371e/1)

Comment: Thanks guys I firured it out "SET new_ID = LAST_INSERT_ID();" this is the correct statemant